# .ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy239

Tags: java, web-services, soap, proxy

I am consuming a SOAP service that gives a proxy object of a class. And from that object (proxy class object) I am calling a method. The service is running smoothly from my local but when I am trying to call that from the machine where the code is deployed, I got this error

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
    **at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy239.getHelloWorldAsString(Unknown Source)**
```

There is no firewall issue (firewall is open for the URL).
Here is the code

```
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:eservice/ws/hello?wsdl");
    QName qname = new QName("http://example.com/","HelloWorldImplService"); 
    Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
    HelloWorld hello = service.getPort(HelloWorld.class);
    System.out.println("helloworld obj: " + hello);
    System.out.println(hello.getHelloWorldAsString("wel come to SOAP"));
```

The first print statement is executed successfully but at second statement I got the above exception saying (i.e. `at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy239.getHelloWorldAsString(Unknown Source))`)